# Transposing a big data file in one line [Python/Unix]

Tags: python, linux, line, transpose

I have a (big) file containing values as such :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 ... N
```

I want to be able to transpose the data values inside this file in on line to get the final result :

```
1 2 3 4 ... N
```

Comment: show use some code that you have tried.

Comment: `tr '\n' ' ' < inputfile`

Comment: Also, I don't think `transpose` really applies here.  That term usually means means the values are being _swapped_ in some way, e.g. transforming rows into columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < inputfile
```

Thanks to John Gordon.